# phantomjs not redirecting (bug?)

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor, end-to-end

I'm using angular with protractor to create my e2e tests.

If I do my tests with Firefox or Chrome everything works fine, but if I do my tests with phantomjs(version 1.9.8) almost all my tests fail because phantomjs is not doing my redirects.

Just a simple test that would be:

- Open a page,
- click on a button that redirect to another url
- check if url change

This test will fail =(

Please, someone could help me?

Comment: PhantomJS supports redirects, maybe not all of them. How about you show a minimal example with a page where this happens?

Comment: Hi,

First of all, thank you for your attention.

I simple test like this below fails with phantomjs + protractor:

beforeEach(function () {
  browser.get("/")
});


it('teste', function() {

  element(by.id('loginBtn')).click().then(function() {
    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual("/login");
  });

})

Comment: Read your question again ... you're not talking about redirects, but about clicking. Take a screenshot and make sure the button that you click is actually there and is visible. Try different ways to click.

Comment: @ArtjomB. when I click at that button (submit button) the data are save and I'm redirect to another page. So I'm redirecting after a button click

Comment: Are you waiting enough time after the click for the URL to change?